# Where is apk located Xamarin Android application?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm assigned to make an app which stores files in

```
/folder of apk/somefolder/subfolder
```

But I can't find where is APK folder located so I can create the folders some folder and subfolder in it and store the files in the complete path

```
/folder of apk/somefolder/subfolder
```

My app is called SomeApp and in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data I have SomeApp.SomeApp. Is this the folder of the APK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `DataDir` (`GetDataDir` in Java)

```
var path = DataDir.Path;
```

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where all private files belonging to this app are stored.

Re: [getDataDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDataDir())

There are also properties such as CacheDir and FileDir provide the "default" files and database directories within that root package path:

```
var cache = CacheDir.Path;
var files = FileDir.Path;
```

Comment: So you think DataDir.Path will return /folder of apk/? (I write the code in C#)

Comment: the path is: /data/user/0/MobileOrder.MobileOrder/files. Can you tell me how can I navigate to there graphically? I mean with the finger not programatically so I can create a folder there.

Comment: Yeah tapping on screen.

Comment: **Not** user accessible unless your phone is rooted, the **app** can access it, anything within the package's file system's sandbox are private files.

Comment: You mean if I want to create folder in /data/user/0/MobileOrder.MobileOrder/files I'm allowed to do that only programatically through code?

Comment: @Profile2ForStack Yes, otherwise you need to use a location that is "public", like the internal/external sdcard (i.e. where Music or Downloads are stored)

Answer (score 0):

search here :
Android/ bin/ Release

for more read below article 
http://www.sweet-web-design.com/wordpress/how-to-build-your-android-app-for-testing-in-visual-studio/2581/

Comment: what I want is not its path on Windows but its path on the android device so I can create the specified folders in it.